# Eigenvectors of a square stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

I was reading the following lecture: [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/statcomp/13/lectures/15/markov.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/statcomp/13/lectures/15/markov.pdf), but I had a problem with a certain paragraph which is this:

> Since **q** is a square, $K \times K$ stochastic matrix, it will have $K$ eigenvectors, say $v_1,...v_k$, and $K$ eigenvalues, $\lambda_1,...\lambda_k$.  (Not all of the eigenvalues are necessarily
> different.) The eigenvectors will form a basis for $R^k$, meaning that we can write an
> arbitrary vector as a linear combination of the eigenvectors.

But if there were eigenvectors with the same eigenvalues wouldn't they just be multiple of each others? So they wouldn't form a basis. Also a stochastic matrix might not have an inverse which would make it impossible for it's rank to equal $K$. Is there something wrong with my reasoning, or have I misunderstood what the writer actually means?

The paragraph is the second one in section 2.1,  if anybody wants to take a look at it.

Comment: identity in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has one eigenvalue with multiplicity of $2$, its eigenspace has dimension $2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenspace for a given eigenvalue can be bigger than one-dimensional. Consider the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Every vector is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$. The eigenspace is the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$. Not all vectors in there are multiples of each other.

In general, you can choose a basis for each eigenspace. Stitching all these bases together gives you a linearly independent system consisting of eigenvectors. In your case, the matrix is diagonalizable, which makes this system also a basis.